# SQL Server Agent 2005 job runs but provides no output

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server

Essentially I have a job which runs in BIDS and as as a stand lone package and while it runs under the SQL Server Agent it doesn't complete properly (no error messages though).

The job steps are:

1) Delete all rows from table;

2) Use For each loop to fill up table from Excel spreasheets;

3) Clean up table.

I've tried this [MS page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760) (steps 1 & 2), didn't see any need to start changing from Server side security.

Also SQLServerCentral.com for [this page](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic506965-148-1.aspx), no resolution.

How can I get error logging or a fix?

I have logged in as the proxy account I'm running this under, and the job runs stand alone but complains that the Excel tables are empty?

Comment: I believe there is a logging mode property that you enable in your package in order to have SSIS log output.

In the SQL Agent job, edit your job step where the package is specified and use the Advanced selection on the left to specify an output file (won't be especially useful for troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled this but as it thinks there are no errors I'm not getting anything useful out of it.

Comment: If packaging logging doesn't do it, I'm not sure what will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix this eventually, thanks for the suggestions.

Basically I logged in with the proxy user account I was running and started to see errors like: "The For each file enumerator is empty"

I copied the project files across, and it turned out that I'd still left a file path (N:/) in the properties of the For Each loop box, although I'd changed the connection properties.  I also had to recreate the variable mapping to get it working.

No wonder people just recreate the whole package(!)

Now fixed and working.